# Material UI with Static Stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, css-in-js

https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/01/css-cssinjs-performance-cost/ and https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2019/the-unseen-performance-costs-of-css-in-js-in-react-apps/ explain the unseen performance costs of CSS-in-JS.

We're developing a data-driven React web app that requires a lot of JS processing. We're trying to optimize the app by reducing the load on the JS main thread. For this purpose, in addition to parallelizing some of the processes on other Web workers, we're thinking of replacing all the CSS-in-JS code with static class-based stylesheets that we manually write and simply import in each component. The issue is that it's extremely difficult to manually override some of Material UI styles because it injects the style into the elements and we cannot simply override them using classes.

What else do you suggest us to do to reduce the JS performance overload by handling all the CSS through static style sheets rather than overloading the JS processing to generate the style sheets in runtime?

Comment: Great Question! Have you come to a solution for this?

Comment: I'm still not sure, but it seems like https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction can solve this issue and that's why Material UI team is promoting it https://mui.com/blog/mui-core-v5/ What do you think?

Comment: Thx for your reply. As i understood emotions `css` function it will also generate styles at runtime. After having a look at the current Github issues with the tag `performance` i'm not that convinced that they fixed the performance issues for larger apps. It's a pity that they haven't switched to a static/build time CSS-in-JS solution with near-zero runtime like Stitches or Vanilla Extract when replacing there CSS-in-JS solution for v5.

Comment: I really like MUI and think it's the most advanced UI Kit for React alone because of the support for more advanced components like `<Autocomplete />` or `<Datepicker />` that many others are missing (right now). So in the end i decided to use Tailwind for now to manage all layout things and simple components and only use MUI for some of the more complex components i mentioned above. I try to avoid using their CSS-in-JS approach as much as possible. It's also relatively easy to setup a theme configuration and use it both for Tailwind and MUI.

Comment: This way the application won't get slow (at least i hope it ) and because of tree shaking the bundle stays relatively small. But to also mention something positive at the end: one promising feature they're implementing right now is providing headless versions of the components. This would allow to reduce the amount of CSS-in-JS bound to their components (and therefore in the app) even further, so maybe this could be interesting for you too. Here is the [Progress Issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/27170).

Comment: And finally some feedback to your initial problem to override some of MUI’s styles with classes. I can only speak for the Tailwind use case, but haven’t had any issues using Tailwind classes and passing them via the `classes` prop. Of course some of them had to be defined with an additional `!important`, which isn't necessarily the most elegant way.  But besides from that it’s working fine for me.